# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

When I run my code, the navegator show me that:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant datos1 - assumed 'datos1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php on line 8

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php on line 8
> No se pudo conectar a la base de datos
> Notice: Undefined index: Teachers_Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php on line 13

> Notice: Undefined index: School_Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php on line 14

> Notice: Undefined variable: Implementation_Quality in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php on line 15

> Notice: Undefined variable: Implementation_Quality in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php on line 17

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\formulario\conexion1.php on line 19

What I do?

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");

if(!$conexion){
echo "Conexión no exitosa";
} else {

$base= mysqli_select_db(datos1);
    if(!$base){
        echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
    }
 }
$Teachers_Name=$_POST['Teachers_Name'];
$School_Name=$_POST['School_Name'];
$Implementation_Quality['Implementation_Quality'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO datos_1 VALUES('$Teachers_Name', 'School_Name', 
'$Implementation_Quality')";

$ejecutar = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$ejecutar){
echo "Hubo algun error";
} else {
 echo "Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're mixing up `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*`, which are different libraries. MYSQL_* is deprecated and no longer available at PHP 7 or larger.

Comment: in here you must set name filed of your table..(You must specify your name field from your table))

    $sql= "INSERT INTO datos_1 (filde1, filde2, filde3) VALUES('$Teachers_Name', 'School_Name', 
    '$Implementation_Quality')";

Comment: You've posted a variety of different error messages, as well as code with a variety of different problems.  The help you're looking for is in the form of introductory tutorials on PHP and MySQL.  Google is a good place to find those.

Comment: @pedramshabani: That's not required if the supplied values successfully map to the table structure.  (Though it's still a good idea to explicitly specify column names.)

Comment: Ok.Thank you David.i don't know it before......

Comment: @Marinowsky: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! As a programmer, it is imperative that you develop the skills needed to debug code that you've written. I strongly recommend you do a read of this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  and the information on the "how to ask" page. StackOverflow is a question answer site. And "Here's my code, it's not working, please help me!" isn't really a *question*. I've provided some tips in an answer, I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$base= mysqli_select_db(datos1);
```

With this:

```
$base= mysqli_select_db($conexion,'datos1');
```

---

replace this:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO datos_1 VALUES('$Teachers_Name', 'School_Name', '$Implementation_Quality')";
```

With this:

```
$sql= 'INSERT INTO datos_1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )';
```

Replace `col1`,`col2` and `col3` with the names of columns in the datos_1 table.
e.g. `... datos_1 (teacher_name, school_name, implementation_quality) VALUES ...`

Note that this is a static string literal. There's no variable substitution. The question marks are bind placeholders which we will reference later.

---

Replace this:

```
$ejecutar = mysql_query($sql);
```

With this:

```
$sth = mysqli_prepare($conexion,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sss', $Teachers_Name, $School_Name, $Implementation_Quality);
$ejecutar = mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);
```

Don't mix `mysql_` functions with `mysqli_` functions. That won't work. (We shouldn't be using *any* `mysql_` functions in new development; the `mysql_` interface functions have been deprecated a *long* time ago, and are finally removed in newest versions of PHP.

---

Do NOT incorporate potentially unsafe values in SQL text. Use prepared statements with bind placeholders. (Or less optimally, properly *escape* any values that are incorporated into the text.)

Recommended:

Little Bobby Tables - Exploits of a Mom  https://xkcd.com/327/

OWASP SQL Injection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection